# Using modules downloaded from npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

i have been reading [this guide on](https://github.com/petehunt/react-howto#learning-react-itself) react where the following paragraph has kind of thrown me.

> For a number of good technical reasons CommonJS modules (i.e.
>   everything in npm) cannot be used natively in the browser. You need a
>   JavaScript “bundler” to “bundle” these modules into .js files that you
>   can include in your web page with a  tag.

I was under the impression that i could do something like `npm install jquery` and then in my `index.html` file reference this through node modules, something like
`<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist.jquery.js">`

Is this not the case, or am I incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are correct. Jquery is a global module not a commonjs module. For other package that use commonjs module, using import/export statement you need a bundler like browserify to bundle it into a single bundle in order to use it in browser

Comment: ah ok, so if the library has used `import/export` then you need to use `browserify` or some other bundler! got it

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the guide you read, examples for those "bundlers" are `webpack`/`browserify`/`systemjs`/etc..

These are what is called as "module-loaders" which basically loads the modules to the browser when running your applications.

These module-loaders have a configuration file.

So if for example yours is `webpack`, after you install `npm install webpack` you'll need to have a `webpack.config.js` that might look as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/boot",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts/,   loader: ["ts-loader"], exclude: /node_modules/ },
        ],
        preLoaders: [
        // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader", exclude: ['node_modules', 'ext-*', 'lib', 'tools'] }
        ]
    },
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Comment: thanks man! got all that, daniel answered my question, thats where my confusion lay

Answer (score 1):

When the jquery library is loaded, it verifies if it is being imported by a bundler/loader or by a script tag:

```
( function( global, factory ) {

"use strict";

if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {

    module.exports = global.document ?
        factory( global, true ) :
        function( w ) {
            if ( !w.document ) {
                throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
            }
            return factory( w );
        };
} else {
    factory( global ); // export globally
}
} )( typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) { /** jQuery definition **/ }
```